# how to fix my ruby on rails app for IE browser? Everything is off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, browser, cross-browser

I built my first rails app but built them using Firefox and Chrome. The web app looks fine in those browsers, but IE is way off. It's nearly unusable (internally as well as the homepage). What is the best way to address this issue without messing up the other browsers?

Should I just resort to doing a browser detect and put up an error message saying it's not optimized for IE?

Answer (score 1):

You should just identify the specific, individual layout problems you see with your site in IE and start fixing them one by one, depending on the issue. There isn't one single answer to making your site render correctly in all browsers, it will likely be a combination of fixes for specific layout issues on your page, and frequently testing in all the browsers you plan to support, to ensure each one is still working after you make a change.

Beyond that, without a more specific description of the rendering issues your site has, there isn't much more direction to give here.

Comment: I noticed that what is really messing up how the website is rendered in IE is due to this Security Warning: "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?" If you choose "Yes", the website is really bad looking. IF you choose "No", it's much better but not as great as Chrome or FF. I have SSL (used the free StartSSL) on my website and on other browsers they don't have any security warnings except on IE. Is it possible to get rid of this and let all webpage content to render?

Comment: It sounds like your CSS file is being requested without SSL. Browsers may complain at you if certain assets on the page, like the CSS file, is not delivered securely. I'd check that you are linking to your CSS file using `https://`, since that will definitely make it look bad (no styles at all).